# Is there a way to combine memberwise comparison within an if-statement in python?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, comparison-operators, multiple-conditions

> I want to check multiple conditions in an if-statement

```
if a:
    # do something
```

a in this case is true for multiple cases a==1, a==2, a==3

instead of writing

```
if a == 1 or a == 2 or a == 3:
    # do something
```

I am trying something like this

```
if a == condition for condition in [1, 2, 3]:
    # do something
```

Comment: `if any(a == condition for condition in [1, 2, 3]):`? But your error doesn't come from that code alone.

Comment: ```The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous``` sounds like a numpy error message.  Have you represented your data correctly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that should be `if a in [1, 2, 3]:`

Comment: If your problem is solved by an answer, please accept it. But if you had a different problem, this is unlikely to be very useful to others.

Comment: I disagree. Neither the question nor the accepted answer mention the correct way to solve the problem in the title. Could be misleading to beginners.

Comment: @hop then the question should be edited and/or a new answer added. Do not add answers to questions. And it's up to the OP which answer they accept; if you think others are better, vote them up.

Comment: The Question I asked was answered by answers given. But this did not solve my actual problem. One of the answers gave me the right hint where to search for the underlying problem (I changed the accepted answer from there to the question which answers the actual question to minimize confusion). And I removed the answer I stated in the question. Hope you guys are fine with those explanations and decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to other answers, your best bet would definately be this logic:

```
if a in set([1, 2, 3]):
    #do something
```

or even better

```
 if a in {1, 2, 3}:
    #do something
```

The thing I want to underline here is the fact that you should use a `set` for that kind of situation. Lookups will be more efficient.

Also, python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) recommend that.

> Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference

Comment: Your first construction would surely be *significantly* slower: `set([1, 2, 3])` than simply checking for membership in `[1,2,3]` because it has to *build the set* every time. Use the set-literal! Then the compiler can optimize! Indeed, the difference between `x in [1,2,3]` and `x in set([1,2,3])` is *much* larger than the difference between `x in [1,2,3]` and `x in {1,2,3}`

Comment: This is why I proposed a second solution. As I said, my goal was to give him an insight on how to easily optimize the solution. But you have a good point, I will update .

Answer (score 2):

You are kind of on the right path. What was required is :

```
if a in [1,2,3]:
   do something
```

As a substitution for

```
if a == 1 or a == 2 or a ==3:
```

As **jonrsharpe** rightly pointed out, maybe you were trying

```
if any( a==condition for condition in [1,2,3] ):
```

which too works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to write is `if a in (1, 2, 3)`

What your are trying to write could be written as

```
if any(a == condition for condition in [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

`The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous` looks like a numpy error message.  If `a` is a numpy ndarray and b contains the values you are testing for, you can do it like this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6)
b = np.array([6,2,9])
if np.any(a == b[:, None]):
    ...
```

or

```
np.any(a[:,None] == b)
```

Which makes use of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

---

Your exception can be reproduced using *my* arrays ...

```
>>> if a == b[:, None]:
    pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#281>", line 1, in <module>
    if a == b[:, None]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
```

Comment: Certainly not standard python as `if a == condition for condition in [1, 2, 3]` is invalid syntax

Comment: Indeed my Problem was, that my "a" had multiple values, which I wasn't aware of

Comment: @vanilla - when something unexpected like that happens it often helps to inspect the operands.  One way to do that is to [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print stuff in the `except` suite. Another strategy might be to [search using the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ValueError%3A+The+truth+value+of+an+array+with+more+than+one+element+is+ambiguous.+Use+a.any()+or+a.all()).

Comment: @NickA - can you explain?

Comment: @wwii you said the error message looks like a numpy error, I was merely saying that it couldnt be standard python error as the code provided by OP just gives a syntax error

Comment: This `ambiguity` error is raised by `numpy` when a boolean array is used in a context that requires a scalar boolean, such as an `if`.  Sometimes it is corrected by using `any` or `all` to reduce those values to one, but more often it means your shouldn't be trying to do this kind of test on an array.